# How do i initialize knockout into my html(index)

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I dont know why its not working correctly as it supposed to do. (im new to this things)
This is my html index:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<p>First name: <strong data-bind = "text: firstName"></strong></p>
<p>Last name: <strong data-bind = "text: lastName"></strong></p>

<script src="js/myscripts.js"></script>
<script src="js/knockout-3.3.0.js"></script>

</body>
```

Below is my js code in file named "myscripts":

```
function AppViewModel() {
    this.firstName = "Bert";
    this.lastName = "Bertington";
}


ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

This shows only this in my browser:

```
First name:

Last name:
```

but should be:

```
First name: Bert

Last name: Bertington
```

In folder named "js" i got 2 files named: myscripts.js and knockout-3.3.0.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the knockout script *before* you load your own script which references knockout.

```
<script src="js/knockout-3.3.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/myscripts.js"></script>
```